# In Bootstrap 5, how do you align a div with the bottom of its container div?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

In the Bootstrap 5 code below there is a div with id "div-in-right-div" which is inside of a div with id "right-div". "div-in-right-div" is aligned with the top of "right-div".
What changes need to be done so that the inner div "div-in-right-div" is aligned vertically with the bottom of the outer div "right-div"?

I thought the class "align-bottom" which I've added to the div with id="right-div"
should do the trick, but it didn't.
I've also added class "align-self-end" to div "div-in-right-div" in addition to the above and that also didn't accomplish what I want.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.7.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
  <style>
    .custom-header {
      max-width: 1200px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background-color: yellow;
    }

    .right-block ul.nav {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .right-block ul.nav li {
      margin-left: 20px;
    }

    .right-block ul.nav li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      position: relative;
    }

    .right-block ul.nav li .icon {
      font-size: 20px;
      margin-right: 5px;
    }

    /* Mobile-specific styling */
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
      /* ... Mobile styles ... */
    }

    /* Large screen specific styling */
    @media (min-width: 992px) {
      .right-block ul.nav li a::before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        width: 0;
        height: 2px;
        background-color: black;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
      }

      .right-block ul.nav li a:hover::before {
        width: 100%;
      }
      
    }
  </style>
  <title>Bootstrap 5 Header Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header class="custom-header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="left-block">
            <!-- Content for the left block -->
            <h3>Left Block</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="central-block text-center">
            <!-- Content for the center block -->
            <h3>Central Block</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 align-bottom" id="right-div">
          <div class="right-block align-self-end" id="div-in-right-div">
            <!-- Content for the right block -->
            <ul class="nav justify-content-end">
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  <i class="bi bi-house icon"></i>
                  <span>Add</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  <i class="bi bi-person icon"></i>
                  <span>Login</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is `d-flex align-items-basline justify-content-end` on #right-div what you're looking for?

Comment: Many of the declarations in your custom CSS could be applied using the applicable Bootstrap classes.

Comment: Like TimR said you should have a look at this: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/flex/

@j08691 I just saw your comment. That's exaclty what i answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could align the #div-in-right-div at the bottom, by adding the classes "d-flex align-items-baseline" to the #right-div. I added also "width: 100%;" to the #div-in-right-div, so it doesn't stick to the left, because of display flex by bootstrap.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.7.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
  <style>
    /* new */
    #div-in-right-div {
        width: 100%;
    }
    /* new end */
    .custom-header {
      max-width: 1200px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background-color: yellow;
    }

    .right-block ul.nav {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .right-block ul.nav li {
      margin-left: 20px;
    }

    .right-block ul.nav li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      position: relative;
    }

    .right-block ul.nav li .icon {
      font-size: 20px;
      margin-right: 5px;
    }

    /* Mobile-specific styling */
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
      /* ... Mobile styles ... */
    }

    /* Large screen specific styling */
    @media (min-width: 992px) {
      .right-block ul.nav li a::before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        width: 0;
        height: 2px;
        background-color: black;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
      }

      .right-block ul.nav li a:hover::before {
        width: 100%;
      }
      
    }
  </style>
  <title>Bootstrap 5 Header Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header class="custom-header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="left-block">
            <!-- Content for the left block -->
            <h3>Left Block</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="central-block text-center">
            <!-- Content for the center block -->
            <h3>Central Block</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 d-flex align-items-baseline" id="right-div">
          <div class="right-block align-self-end" id="div-in-right-div">
            <!-- Content for the right block -->
            <ul class="nav justify-content-end">
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  <i class="bi bi-house icon"></i>
                  <span>Add</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  <i class="bi bi-person icon"></i>
                  <span>Login</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: inline-grid;` or `display: grid;` style to `#right-div`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.7.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
  <style>
    .custom-header {
      max-width: 1200px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background-color: yellow;
    }

    .right-block ul.nav {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .right-block ul.nav li {
      margin-left: 20px;
    }

    .right-block ul.nav li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      position: relative;
    }

    .right-block ul.nav li .icon {
      font-size: 20px;
      margin-right: 5px;
    }

    /* Mobile-specific styling */
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
      /* ... Mobile styles ... */
    }

    /* Large screen specific styling */
    @media (min-width: 992px) {
      .right-block ul.nav li a::before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        width: 0;
        height: 2px;
        background-color: black;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
      }

      .right-block ul.nav li a:hover::before {
        width: 100%;
      }
      
    }
    #right-div{
        display: inline-grid;
    }
  </style>
  <title>Bootstrap 5 Header Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header class="custom-header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="left-block">
            <!-- Content for the left block -->
            <h3>Left Block</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="central-block text-center">
            <!-- Content for the center block -->
            <h3>Central Block</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 align-bottom" id="right-div">
          <div class="right-block align-self-end" id="div-in-right-div">
            <!-- Content for the right block -->
            <ul class="nav justify-content-end">
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  <i class="bi bi-house icon"></i>
                  <span>Add</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  <i class="bi bi-person icon"></i>
                  <span>Login</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.7.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
  <style>
    .custom-header {
      max-width: 1200px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background-color: yellow;
    }

    .right-block ul.nav {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .right-block ul.nav li {
      margin-left: 20px;
    }

    .right-block ul.nav li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      position: relative;
    }

    .right-block ul.nav li .icon {
      font-size: 20px;
      margin-right: 5px;
    }

    /* Mobile-specific styling */
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
      /* ... Mobile styles ... */
    }

    /* Large screen specific styling */
    @media (min-width: 992px) {
      .right-block ul.nav li a::before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        width: 0;
        height: 2px;
        background-color: black;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
      }

      .right-block ul.nav li a:hover::before {
        width: 100%;
      }
      
    }
  </style>
  <title>Bootstrap 5 Header Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header class="custom-header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="left-block">
            <!-- Content for the left block -->
            <h3>Left Block</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="central-block text-center">
            <!-- Content for the center block -->
            <h3>Central Block</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 align-bottom" id="right-div">
          <div class="right-block align-self-end" id="div-in-right-div">
            <!-- Content for the right block -->
            <ul class="nav justify-content-end">
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  <i class="bi bi-house icon"></i>
                  <span>Add</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  <i class="bi bi-person icon"></i>
                  <span>Login</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Explain your answer please. Don't just dump code and expect that everyone will understand what it was that you did.

Comment: @j08691 This answer doesn't even work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).